# Whats the terminology for defining a point on a triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, geometric-interpretation

There are 2 common methods of representing a point on a 2d/3d triangle.

- 2 numbers *(often called "UV coordinates" in 3D graphics)*:
  Where 2 edges of the triangle are axes, which the point is translated along.
- 3 numbers *(barycentric weights)*:
  The point is the product of the triangle, where each point is multiplied by the corresponding weight.

I've seen some source-code that makes references to both methods as barycentric coordinates.

Whats the correct terminology for these 2 methods of defining a point on a triangle?

---

*Note, I may know the answer to these but looking on-line I didn't find good definitive explanations that distinguish between these 2 methods.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way is typically *bilinear interpolation* in which a triangle is seen as a rectangle with two coincident vertices by collapsing an edge. Each edge you choose will given a different parametrization of the triangle.

The second way is *barycentric interpolation* or *barycentric coordinates*.

The two methods are different because the isoparametric curves $u=u_0$ and $v=v_0$ are different.